# How to distribute two independent rows of bits

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider two independent rows of 100 bits. The bits are mutually independent and have an equal chance to be 0 or 1. The first row is being read and during that process there is a chance $\epsilon$ that there is a mistake while reading the first row. The second row is being read without mistakes. Let $X$ be the amount of identical symbols while reading the first and second row. How is $X$ distributed?

I would say that $X$~$bin(100, 1/2)$ and that the $\epsilon$ won't change that probability, as there is an equal chance that a bit is misread. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct. The first row induces a row of outcomes (wrongly or not wrongly read does not matter). The row of outcomes is fixed. Then the second row is read and by every bit there is a probability of $\frac12$ on success (i.e. it equalizes the outcome).